# root namespace is added into the <xades:SignedProperties>

Tags: xml-signature, xades4j

library: apache Santuario +  xades4j.

using xpathto select elements and sign them.

If I try to sign a simple XML without a namespace and verify the signature, it works well , but if the XML defines a namespace, for example the XML following:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <element1tobesigned.../>
    <element2tobesigned.../>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

and the exception was found when verifying the signature

```
    858  WARN  [main] org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference     - Verification failed for URI "#xmldsig-5fb20abe-b14c-4d84-a908-e22e776cd6f1-signedprops"
    858  WARN  [main] org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference     - Expected Digest: q0WnWFf9j0kcT46t5cXmcPnVvu5o51oAcmej/SjCazQ=
    858  WARN  [main] org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference     - Actual Digest: 41zXKVkRCsxUYpNZXW5b9KkZlTC9LM9WA8O7WHQz1Rg=

    xades4j.verification.ReferenceValueException: Reference '#xmldsig-5fb20abe-b14c-4d84-a908-e22e776cd6f1-signedprops' cannot be validated
```

the cause is that XML namespace (urn:hl7-org:v3) was added into the xades:SignedProperties then the digest became different .

```
858  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream     - Pre-digested input
858  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream   - <xades:SignedProperties xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" ........./>
```

here is the signature generation code

```
    XadesTSigningProfile profile = new XadesTSigningProfile(keyProvider);
    profile.withTimeStampTokenProvider(TestTimeStampTokenProvider.class)
    .withAlgorithmsProviderEx(ExclusiveC14nForTimeStampsAlgorithmsProvider.class);  

    XadesSigner signer = profile.newSigner();   

    DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference("")
    .withTransform(new ExclusiveCanonicalXMLWithoutComments())
    .withTransform( new XPathTransform(xPath);

    SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects().withSignedDataObject(obj1);

changed 2012-11-20 begin

//  signer.sign(dataObjs, docToSign.getDocumentElement() ); 
       new Enveloped(signer).sign(docToSign.getDocumentElement());

changed 2012-11-20 end
```

and here is the verify code

```
NodeList signatureNodeList = getSigElement(getDocument("my/my-document.signed.bes.countersign.xml"));

for (int i = 0; i < signatureNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element signatureNode = (Element) signatureNodeList.item(i);
    verifySignature(signatureNode, new XadesVerificationProfile(VerifierTestBase.validationProviderMySigs));
    log.info("successful validation");          
}

public static XAdESForm verifySignature(Element sigElem,
            XadesVerificationProfile p) throws Exception {
        XAdESVerificationResult res = p.newVerifier().verify(sigElem, null);

        return res.getSignatureForm();
    }
```

It looks like that there is a document about this problem in Apache Santuario FAQ ,

```
2.6. I sign a document and when I try to verify using the same key, it fails
After you have created the XMLSignature object, before you sign the document, you must embed the signature element in the owning document (using a call to XMLSignature.getElement() to retrieve the newly created Element node from the signature) before calling the XMLSignature.sign() method,

During canonicalisation of the SignedInfo element, the library looks at the parent and ancestor nodes of the Signature element to find any namespaces that the SignedInfo node has inherited. Any that are found are embedded in the canonical form of the SignedInfo. (This is not true when Exclusive Canonicalisation is used, but it is still good practice to insert the element node prior to the sign() method being called).

If you have not embedded the signature node in the document, it will not have any parent or ancestor nodes, so it will not inherit their namespaces. If you then embed it in the document and call verify(), the namespaces will be found and the canonical form of SignedInfo will be different to that generated during sign().
```

also there is  a document about this problem as following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759909/1809884

It looks like  that it is not a bug of xades4j, but  a xml signature problem.

--add 2012-11-15

```
here is how to get the docToSign . in fact , i just reused the code in class  SignatureServicesTestBase . so i am sure that it is namespaceaware. 
static
    {
           DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
           db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    }
 public static Document getDocument(String fileName) throws Exception
    {
        String path = toPlatformSpecificXMLDirFilePath(fileName);
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(path));
        // Apache Santuario now uses Document.getElementById; use this convention for tests.
        Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(elem);
        return doc;
    }

and docToSign  is return by calling SignatureServicesTestBase.getDocument()

Document docToSign = SignatureServicesTestBase.getDocument("my/cdamessage.xml");
```

and the SignedProperties element as following

```
<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SigningTime>2012-11-15T13:58:26.167+09:00</xades:SigningTime>
<xades:SigningCertificate>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>4btVb5gQ5cdcNhGpvDSWQZabPQrR9jf1x8e3YF9Ajss=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Itermediate,OU=CC,O=ISEL,C=PT</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>-119284162484605703133798696662099777223</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>vm5QpbblsWV7fCYXotPhNTeCt4nk8cLFuF36L5RJ4Ok=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TestCA,OU=CC,O=ISEL,C=PT</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>-46248926895392336918291885380930606289</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>AUaN+IdhKQqxIVmEOrFwq+Dn22ebTkXJqD3BoOP/x8E=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
<xades:IssuerSerial>
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=TestCA,OU=CC,O=ISEL,C=PT</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>-99704378678639105802976522062798066869</ds:X509SerialNumber>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
</xades:SignedProperties>
```

also ,  i use xpath to get the elements to be signed, and namespace(xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" ) is add into the result as well .

```
543  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy     - setElement("ds:Transform", "null")
544  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy     - setElement("dsig-xpath:XPath", "null")
658  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream     - Pre-digested input:
658  DEBUG [main] org.apache.xml.security.utils.DigesterOutputStream     - <component xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" Id="ES" contextConductionInd="true" typeCode="COMP">
        <section classCode="DOCSECT" moodCode="EVN">
          <code code="ES" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="SectionCode" codeSystemVersion="1.0" displayName="english"></code>
          <text>english</text>
        </section>
      </component>
```

something wrong with xpath ?  xpath is driving my crazy .  I think i have to study xpath from beginning  now.

chris

Comment: I don't think the fact that you quoted from Santuario FAQ is actually a problem.. it's just the way it is. You need to append the signature element to the DOM tree in order to resolve references in the first place. Nevertheless, the namespace declaration being included in signed properties seems strange.

Comment: thanks. lgoncalves . could you please show me how to " append the signature element to the DOM tree in order to resolve references in the first place" using XAdES4J API .   My project has been pending for about 7 days. A line of code will help  greatly.

Comment: XAdES4j does that for you already during signature production. I was just pointing out that the problem wouldn't be there.

Comment: How are you loading "docToSign"? Is it namespaceaware? Can you post the SignedProperties element as seen after signature production?

Comment: thanks  lgoncalves . plsease search "add 2012-11-15" in this page.

Comment: You're missing the call to dbf.setNamespaceAware(true). I'm not sure if that's what's causing the problem, but can be. The signature XML looks ok. Btw, are you sure about the two consecutive XPath transforms? The second one doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: thanks lgoncalves . I do have this line of code  dbf.setNamespaceAware(true)  in my project , but it is missing here . something might go wrong when i pasted and edited this page.
Just now , i found that if i changed this line of code
  signer.sign(dataObjs, docToSign.getDocumentElement() );
to 
  new Enveloped(signer).sign(docToSign.getDocumentElement()); 
it seem that the signature can be verified successfully , but the xpath  transform is missing.  as a result , the whole document was signed.
Could you please telle me  how can i use  new Enveloped(signer) with xpath transform .

Comment: plsease search "2012-11-20" in this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an [enveloped signature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-Overview) but the enveloped signature transform is missing! Since the whole document is being signed the signature node itself has to be excluded, because some of its contents change after signature calculation.

Can't believe how I didn't see it until you mentioned the Enveloped class. Btw, this class is just an utility class for simple, straightforward enveloped sigantures. It robably shouldn't even be there. You can just add the transform yourself:

```
DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference("")
.withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform())
.withTransform(new ExclusiveCanonicalXMLWithoutComments())
...
```

Comment: thanks lgoncalves . you helped me greatly . and thanks for your good job - xades4j.